# is there any way to get an xml response from web server?

Tags: xml, api, rest, qt

I am using a REST API to get a response from a server. I am using the 'qt C++' framework for retrieving the data(in XML format). Is there any way to connect to the server and receive the xml response? I have also attached a snippet for your reference, the variable result value its showing up as NULL. I am a beginner in qt C++.

[image]

Comment: You are probably getting a network error of somekind if the response is empty. Check first reply->error(); for any generic network errors and then reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt(); for http error code.

Answer (score 0):

reply->readAll() function's return can be captured directly into a QString variable, If you have no problem in sending the body of the request from the server component than what you can do is to use the string captured and parse the xml from there. Look at the link here -> [XML string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255219/how-to-parse-an-xml-string-in-qt). By the way do not use images for code use the stackowerflow's code quotes.